# Python - Urllib.Request - Change location of downloaded file

Tags: python, urllib

How can i choose the position in which the downloaded file is stored? My code:

```
import urllib.request
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'
        headers = {'User-Agent':user_agent,}
        request = urllib.request.Request("http://download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip",None,headers)
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
        data = response.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. So you've got `data`:

```
ofile = open(where_you_want_to_store_the_data,"wb")
ofile.write(data)
ofile.close()
```

For a cleaner way you can use `urlretrieve`:

```
urlretrieve(url, "/path/to/something.txt")
```

Comment: But now i get: "TypeError: must be str, not bytes". I download a .zip file, does this may cause the error?
But how to i get my user_agent in the request in your second example?

Comment: Your first example, i need the user_agent in my request, how do i manage that with your second example?

Comment: @binaryBigInt, if you're downloading binary files you should open the file in binary mode. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Ah, thanks, now it works to that point that i get another error message. Strangely i get "permission denied" on every folder i try to write the file on?

Comment: @binaryBigInt, that means you don't have enough permissions to write to them. Check under which user you're running this and try to do it with `sudo`.

Comment: How can i call "sudo" in a python program? I am also running under windows.

Comment: @binaryBigInt, ah, okay, this won't work then :P That's odd, actually, there shouldn't be any errors. Check where you're trying to write the file, try to write it to the Desktop or smth like this.

Comment: I also get a permission denied if i try to write it on the desktop, it looks like the only place it works is in the same folder with this code:
"ofile = open("./%s" % ("test.zip"), "wb")"
Does anyone know if urllib.request is part of the "python core module"?